# Passing date to hql query from Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date

I am trying to figure out how to get a date that is exactly one year less than the current date and pass it as a parameter to HQL.

I tried to use Calendar. But I am lost in converting this to right Date format required for Oracle.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(new Date());  
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
String dateLimit = cal.getTime().toString();
Date dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(dateLimit); // This one shows I need to either wrap it up in try catch or specify in throws.

//Date cutOffDate = dateFormatter.parse(dateLimit); //tried this. no avail

queryBuilder.append(" and c.dateOfContact >= :cutOffDate ");
parameters.put("cutOffDate", dateFormatter);
```

Alternatively, are there any Hibernate built-in function for date manipulation? All I want is to pass a date to the query, which is a year less than the current date.

Oracle date format is dd-MMM-yyyy. (ex: 21-Jun-2013)

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work:

```
parameters.put("cutOffDate", cal.getTime());
```

If the type of c.dateOfContact is java.util.Date or java.sql.Date than cal.getTime() has to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d =  cal.getTime();
Query query = em.createQuery(QUERYSTRING)setParameter("cutOffDate", d);
```

The above should work, don't format your date as a string, because then you will be comparing a `String` and a `Date`.